# Algorithm to apply Lasso and Ridge in Gradient descent

Tags: machine-learning, regression, linear-regression, gradient-descent

This my Gradient descent function -

```
Take ϴ as 0,0
Till n iterations
    hypothesis = Dot product of ϴ and feature vector X
    loss = hypothesis - target vector
    descent = Dot product of Transpose of X and loss divided by the size of X
    ϴ = theta - alpha*grad
```

Now how to modify this to include Lasso and Ridge regression?

Comment: You add one more step to project $\theta$ on the constraint set like so: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proximal_gradient_methods_for_learning

Comment: @Emre What about lasso with momentum

Comment: I think it makes more sense to do the projection after incorporating momentum, but you can [read more about it yourself](http://www.seas.ucla.edu/~vandenbe/236C/lectures/fgrad.pdf).